# How much abstraction is too much?

Tags: language-agnostic, oop, abstraction

In an object-oriented program: **How much abstraction is too much? How much is just right?**

I have always been a nuts and bolts kind of guy. I understood the concept behind high levels of encapsulation and abstraction, but always felt instinctively that adding too much would just confuse the program.

I always tried to shoot for an amount of abstraction that left no empty classes or layers. And where in doubt, instead of adding a new layer to the hierarchy, I would try and fit something into the existing layers.

However, recently I've been encountering more highly abstracted systems.  Systems where everything that could require a representation later in the hierarchy gets one up front. This leads to a lot of empty layers, which at first seems like bad design. However, on second thought I've come to realize that leaving those empty layers gives you more places to hook into in the future without much refactoring. It leaves you greater ability to add new functionality on top of the old without doing nearly as much work to adjust the old.

The two risks of this seem to be that you could get the layers you need wrong. In this case one would wind up still needing to do substantial refactoring to extend the code and would still have a ton of never used layers. But depending on how much time you spend coming up with the initial abstractions, the chance of screwing it up, and the time that could be saved later if you get it right - it may still be worth it to try.

The other risk I can think of is the risk of over doing it and never needing all the extra layers. But is that really so bad? Are extra class layers really so expensive that it is much of a loss if they are never used? The biggest expense and loss here would be time that is lost up front coming up with the layers. But much of that time still might be saved later when one can work with the abstracted code rather than more low-level code.

**So when is it too much? At what point do the empty layers and extra "might need" abstractions become overkill? How little is too little? Where's the sweet spot?**

Are there any dependable rules of thumb you've found in the course of your career that help you judge the amount of abstraction needed?

Comment: How long is a piece of string??? ;)

Comment: Should be CW IMHO, as it doesn't have **an** answer

Comment: Why Java apps tend to have more abstractions compared to C#?

Comment: @Goz depends on language, e.g. Pascal says it does have a max length, however intelligent (c) people know it does not.

Comment: Too much abstraction is the stuff of death-marches.  I am working through a large legacy application that is so abstracted that it literally takes hours to find the code executed when a button is clicked on an interface.  This application combines WPF, Dependency Injection, and mocking in a very detrimental way.  Too much abstraction is an impediment to maintaining a code base.  This is an important topic and should be discussed.  Too much abstraction can literally leave good companies and organizations in ruins.  This is no exaggeration.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> So when is it too much? At what point
>   do the empty layers and extra "might
>   need" abstractions become overkill?
>   How little is too little? Where's the
>   sweet spot?

I don't think there is a definitive answer to these questions. Experience is needed to develop a feeling of what is "too much" and "too little". Maybe the usage of some metric or quality control tools can help, but it's hard to generalize. It mostly depends on each case.

Here are a few links that might inspire you in the quest of answers:

- [You ain't gonna need it](http://c2.com/xp/YouArentGonnaNeedIt.html)
- [The use/reuse paradox](https://dzone.com/articles/usereuse-paradox)
- [Project triangle: good, fast, cheap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_triangle)
- [All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection (David Wheeler)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirection)

Development is all about finding the right balance between the various tensions that are present in any software engineering effort.

Comment: This is a popular one about the hazards of making frameworks too generic. Funny stuff!

http://discuss.joelonsoftware.com/default.asp?joel.3.219431.12

Comment: I know this is old, but I believe it also depends on the team your working with. I worked with a developer who added abstraction to already abstracted functionality. Which made debugging his work EXTREMELY annoying whenever he wasn't around.

Answer (score 35):

> How little is too little?

When you keep working with "low level" elements on a routine basis and you constantly feel like you don';t want to be doing this. Abstract 'em away.

> So when is it too much?

When you can't make bits and pieces of some code parts on a regular basis and have to debug them down to the previous layer. You feel this particular layer does not contribute anything, just an obstacle. Drop it.

> Where's the sweet spot?

I like to apply the pragmatic approach. If you see a need for an abstraction and understand how it will improve your life, go for it. If you've heard there should be "officially" an extra layer of abstraction but you're not clear why, don't do it but research first. If somebody insists on abstracting something but cannot clearly explain what if will bring, tell them to go away.

Answer (score 34):

The point of abstractions is to **factor out** common properties from the specific ones, like in the mathematical operation:

```
ab + ac => a(b + c)
```

Now you do the same thing with two operations instead of three. This factoring made our expression simpler.

A typical example of an abstraction is the file system. For example, you want your program to be able to write to many kinds of storage devices: pen drives, SD cards, hard drives, etc...

If we didn't have a file system, we would need to implement the direct disk writing logic, the pen drive writing logic and the SD card writing logic. But all of these logics have something in common: they create files and directories, so this common things can be abstracted away, by creating an abstraction layer, and providing an interface to the hardware vendor to do the specific stuff.

The more the things share a common property. The more beneficial an abstraction can be:

```
ab + ac + ad + ae + af
```

to:

```
a(b + c + d + e + f)
```

This would reduce the 9 operations to 5.

Basically each good abstraction roughly halves the complexity of a system.

You always need at least two things sharing a common property to make an abstraction useful. Of course you tear a single thing apart so it looks like an abstraction, but it does not mean it's useful:

```
10 => 5 * 2
```

You cannot define the word "common" if you have only one entity.

So to answer your question. **You have enough abstractions if they making your system as simple as possible.**

*(In my examples, addition connects the parts of the system, while multiplication defines an abstract-concrete relationship.)*

Comment: This answer describes using abstractions to keep code DRY, but it doesn't touch on other important/meaningful uses of abstraction -- e.g. SOLID or GRASP patterns, and metaprogramming contracts that enforce separation of concerns or usage consistency.

Comment: this is completely untrue. if you write a code that doesn't repeat itself in a single line, you will spend around 1 year, and the guy who is going to give it maintenance after your leav the job, will spend another half year in understanding your code. So, it is completely the opposite:  every abstraction you add -> contributes to more complexity to the system.

Answer (score 13):

In theory, it *should* be a matter of simple math using only three (fairly simple) variables:

- S = savings from use
- C = cost of the extra abstractions
- P = probability of use

If S * P > C , then the code is good. If S * P < C, then it's bad.

The reason that's purely theoretical, however, is that you generally can't guess at the probability of use or the savings you'll get from using it. Worse, you can't guess or or usually even *measure* the cost of its presence.

At least some people have drawn a conclusion from this. In TDD, the standard mantra is "you ain't gonna need it" (YAGNI). Simply put, anything that doesn't directly contribute toward the code meeting its current requirements is considered a bad thing. In essence, they've concluded that the probability of use is so low, that including such extra code is *never* justified.

Some of this comes back to "bottom up" versus "top down" development. I tend to think of bottom up development as "library development" -- I.e. instead of developing a specific application, you're really developing libraries for the kinds of things you'll need in the application. The thinking is that with a good enough library, you can develop almost any application of that general type relatively easily.

Quite a bit also depends on the size of the project. Huge projects that stay in use for decades justify a lot more long-term investment than smaller projects that are discarded and replaced much more quickly. This has obvious analogs in real life as well. You don't worry nearly as much about the fit, finish, or workmanship in a disposable razor you'll throw away in less than a week as you do in something like a new car that you'll be using for the next few years.

Answer (score 12):

Simply put, there is too much abstraction if the code is difficult to understand.

Now this isn't to say that you should hard code everything, because that's the easiest code to write and read.

The easiest test is to either put it down for a few days, pick it back up and ask yourself, does this make any sense.  A better approach is to give it to someone else, and see if they can make heads or tails of it.

Comment: "There is too much abstraction if the code is difficult to understand" for who to understand? I've started working on horrendously complicated code bases, then after a couple of months / years can easily find my way around. Also, I've worked with hard coded stuff that was impossible to understand without inserting a couple of meaningful abstractions.

Comment: What I mean is that if the code is difficult because of the abstraction, then there is too much.  I'm not saying that code without abstraction is difficult to read, but you should be able look at the code and say, "Ok point A goes to point B.  That makes sense."

Comment: I agree with Kevin. For example, sometimes I create a shell script to do repetitive work, but then I forget how EXACTLY the script works so end up just using the underlying commands. For example, with 'du' scripts: what directory do I need to be in for executing the script? will the output file be placed in the current directory? is the script asynchronous or blocking? (the exact script I have, called disk_usage is basically "nohup du > disk_usage_recursive.txt &" but I end up just typing this command every type).

Comment: I agree. I have seen code that creates an abstraction (Class) with 2 functions and 2 variables.  This could be done with parameters, but no, the developer abstracted it with an interface, just to change some boolean values.

Answer (score 3):

The reality is that it depends on how well you can look into the future.  You want to plan for changes you can foresee without creating too many extra layers.  If you have a design that transfers data between systems, go ahead and create an interface and use the planned implementation as the default.  For example, you use FTP to move files around but know the standard will be message-based (or whatever) next year.

As for layers within the design, sometimes the added layers make it easier to write smaller classes.  It's ok to add conceptual layers if it means the concrete classes become straight forward.

Answer (score 1):

See item `(6a)` of [RFC 1925](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1925.html) and know that it is indeed true. The only problems you can't fix by adding abstraction layers are those caused by having too many abstraction layers. (In particular, every piece of abstraction makes the whole thing harder to understand.)

Answer (score 1):

Every abstraction that is not actually used is too much. The simpler a system, the easier it is to change. Abstraction layers nearly always make systems more complicated.

OTOH, it's certainly possible to program a complex, unmaintainable mess without any kind of abstraction, and sometimes, "standardized" abstraction layers can help structure a system better than most people would be able to do on their own.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR**

There is no absolute right level of abstraction. A good code-level abstraction can only be discussed in the context of the programmers working on the code and reflects the programmers' actual mental model.

---

Abstraction has no *intrinsic* value whatsoever. The CPUs couldn't care less about what abstraction you are using in your code. On fact from the computation perspective, abstraction is detrimental. That's why higher-level programming language runs slower than lower-level language.

The reason for doing it is because we humans have a finite cognitive ability with a very small amount of working memory. By abstraction, we break up problems into smaller subproblems that our tiny brain can actually process. **Therefore, the value of abstraction must be evaluated in the context of the programmers who write, maintain, and use the code.**

How much abstraction is too much depends on the relative complexity of the problem to the programmers? No sane person would think it is a good idea to factor `x = x + 1` into a `plus_one` function. Why? because it is already a trivial problem everyone can solve without effort. In contrast, A find the greatest common divider function would be considered a good thing to have because it is a complex enough problem that most people will have to put in quite a bit of cognitive effort to solve.

Abstraction is often considered synonymous with code refactoring and avoids code duplication. But they are actually different things. code duplication is often a sign that you can probably make the problem easier to think about by adding some extra abstraction, but it is not necessarily always true. This is what most people who "over-engineer" and "over-abstract" get wrong. Abstraction is the mental model of how you break down the problem into sub-program and **a good code-level abstraction should reflect that same mental model.** Abstraction should make your code easier to think about not harder.

Other answers to this question also mentioned easier to adapt to future changes as a reason for abstraction. I think that is another misconception. If abstraction is only needed to make code easier to adapt to future changes, then logically it must also be true that if I know there will be no changes to the requirement, then there is no need for any abstraction at all which is clearly false. What's really happening here is by foreseeing any potential change we will have, we are altering the problem to solve it in the first place hence a different way to abstract as a solution to that different problem.

It is also worth pointing out that people can and usually do have different mental models. An abstraction that makes perfect sense might cause a serious headache to someone else. So if you're working in a team environment it is important to get a consensus on at least the high-level abstraction.